# Accessing Django on a secondary device

Tags: python, django, csrf

I am trying to access Django from a secondary device i.e. android phone. I have made sure that

1. The laptop I am running Django on is connected to the same network as my secondary device.
2. I have turned off the firewall on my laptop
3. I configured CSRF to accept POST requests a trusted origin in settings.py

Thereafter running `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` , the POST requests on my website works when I access it from the laptop I am running Django from. However, when I use the same link `http://192.168.16.130:8000/` on my phone, the POST requests don't work.

```
import os 
from pathlib import Path 

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'. BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production! DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.16.130', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost', '0.0.0.0']

# !!! Added for CSRF protection

# CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [ 
    "http://0.0.0.0:8000",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://192.168.16.130:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000", ]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://0.0.0.0:8000",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://192.168.16.130:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000", ]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [ 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', ]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with', ]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',                      # !!! Added for CSRF 
    'hospital' ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',                # !!! Added for CSRF
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',               # !!! Added for CSRF  ]
```

Output I got after accessing the website from my phone:

[image]

When I click on buttons on the website, the buttons don't work, showing that the POST requests are not working when accessed from my phone.

I am not sure why this does not work. I have been stuck here for quite some time and hope to seek assistance!

Comment: Can you share the django console output when you're trying to access the site via mobile? The configuration you made in settings.py is correct.

Comment: I have just updated it shown in the above image

Comment: What are "the buttons" that don't work? How are they defined?

Answer (score -1):

just start your django server on your Network

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.16.130:8000
```

make request on phone

Comment: OP is already doing something like this, as they can access it from the phone.